# Update a text field in BB OS 6 when a listener method is invoked

Tags: blackberry, java-me

For the GUI portion of my app, how could I update the RichTextField when my batteryStatusChange method is invoked that changes on the spot?

I was thinking of calling a set method and then having RichTextField get that new number, but it will make a long list of lines unless I delete the textfield before I add a new one.

Something like the battery percentage number under Device Information or the signal strength that changes on the spot.

**Edit:** Figured it out using setText

```
public void batteryStatusChange(int status) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if ((status & DeviceInfo.BSTAT_LEVEL_CHANGED) != 0)
        {           
            batteryStatusField.setText(getBatteryLevel());      

        }
    }
```

Comment: you can invalidate the manager in which you are adding the richtextfield

Comment: Do you simply want to update the text of RichTextField without extra remove/add operation? You can remove unnecessary code from what you have posted, and try to post the code that related to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
batteryStatusField.setText(getBatteryLevel());

    public String getBatteryLevel() {
    return Integer.toString(DeviceInfo.getBatteryLevel()) + " %";
}
```

Got it to work with this code above by putting it inside my batteryStatusChange listener function. Later I will add in more parameters after the function getBatteryLevel() to keep my default formatting.

My battery app in progress
[image]